# TIKZ: Evaluate declared functions inside `foreach`

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to write a loop to plot a rectangle showing the `Midpoint Rule` using pgfplots, but cannot evaluate the function to draw it. (around the end of code). Actual code isn't compiling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    integral axis/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        enlarge y limits=upper,
        axis equal image, width=12cm,
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
        ytick=\empty,
        xticklabel style={font=\small, text height=1.5ex, anchor=north},
        samples=100
    },
    integral/.style={
            domain=2:8,
            samples=7
    },
    integral fill/.style={
            integral,
            draw=none, fill=#1,
            %on layer=axis background
    },
    integral fill/.default=cyan!10,
    integral line/.style={
            integral,
            very thick,
            draw=#1
    },
    integral line/.default=black
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % The function that is used for all the plots
    declare function={f=x/5-cos(deg(x*1.85))/2+2;}
]
\begin{axis}[
    integral axis,
    ymin=0,
    xmin=0.75, xmax=9.25,
    domain=1.5:8.5,
    xtick={2,2.5,3,3.5,...,8},
    xticklabels={$x_0$, $x_{1/2}$, $x_1$,$x_{3/2}$,$x_2$,$x_{5/2}$,$x_3$,,,,$x_{N-1}$,$x_{N-\frac{1}{2}}$,$x_N$},
    axis on top
]
% The filled area under the approximate integral
\addplot [integral fill=cyan!15] {f} \closedcycle;

% The highlighted segment
%\addplot [integral fill=cyan!35, domain=6:7, samples=2] {f} \closedcycle;

% The function
\addplot [very thick, cyan!75!blue] {f} node [anchor=south] {$y=f(x)$};

% The approximate integral
\addplot [integral line=black] {f};

% The vertical lines between the segments
\addplot [integral, ycomb] {f};

% Issue is here.
\foreach \i in {2.5,3.5,...,7.5} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\f \i};
    \draw (\i-.5,\y) rectangle (\i+.5,0);
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pgfplots comes with its own foreach version, which you may want to use here. Notice that you did not specify a version. In older versions of pgfplots you need to add `axis cs:` to the coordinates in the loop. I adjusted your function such that it is really a function of a variable, otherwise you cannot use it in the `\draw` commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
    integral axis/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        enlarge y limits=upper,
        axis equal image, width=12cm,
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
        ytick=\empty,
        xticklabel style={font=\small, text height=1.5ex, anchor=north},
        samples=100
    },
    integral/.style={
            domain=2:8,
            samples=7
    },
    integral fill/.style={
            integral,
            draw=none, fill=#1,
            %on layer=axis background
    },
    integral fill/.default=cyan!10,
    integral line/.style={
            integral,
            very thick,
            draw=#1
    },
    integral line/.default=black
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % The function that is used for all the plots
    declare function={f(\x)=\x/5-cos(deg(\x*1.85))/2+2;}
]
\begin{axis}[
    integral axis,
    ymin=0,
    xmin=0.75, xmax=9.25,
    domain=1.5:8.5,
    xtick={2,2.5,3,3.5,...,8},
    xticklabels={$x_0$, $x_{1/2}$, $x_1$,$x_{3/2}$,$x_2$,$x_{5/2}$,$x_3$,,,,$x_{N-1}$,$x_{N-\frac{1}{2}}$,$x_N$},
    axis on top
]
% The filled area under the approximate integral
\addplot [integral fill=cyan!15] {f(x)} \closedcycle;

% The highlighted segment
%\addplot [integral fill=cyan!35, domain=6:7, samples=2] {f} \closedcycle;

% The function
\addplot [very thick, cyan!75!blue] {f(x)} node [anchor=south] {$y=f(x)$};

% The approximate integral
\addplot [integral line=black] {f(x)};

% The vertical lines between the segments
\addplot [integral, ycomb] {f(x)};
% Issue is here.

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2.5,3.5,...,7.5}{
    \draw[thick,blue] (#1-0.5,{f(#1)}) rectangle({#1+.5},0);
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could plot these bars also with a `bar` plot. That is, you could replace the loop by

```
\addplot [blue,thick,ybar,bar width=1,samples at={2.5,3.5,...,7.5}] {f(x)};
```

Comment: Mr @marmot, thank you one more time. Just for curiosity, is possible to add some discrete evaluated points, lets say in `f(x)`, at some sample positions without to add a line that connects each sampled value?

Comment: found: `only marks`.

Comment: @Lin Yes, that's how this can be done. (I'm already in hibernation mode. ;-)